# Given a tuple t of strings, compute the tuple consisting of all strings in t containing the character @

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I need a 'one-line' Python statement that produces a tuple only containing strings with '@' in them.

---

```
Input:
    tuple_1 = ('asdf@', 'asdf')      #the given (not included in the 2 lines)
```

### my attempt : 2 lines

```
for string in tuple_1:                       
    if '@' in string: tuple_2 = (string)
```

---

```
Out: 
    tuple_2 = ('asdf@')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of tryouts I just achieved to solve it:

```
tuple_1 = ('asdf@', 'asdf')

tuple_2 = ()

for elem in [item for item in tuple_1 if '@' in item]: tuple_2 = tuple_2 + (elem,)

print tuple_2
```

I hope this is what you need! I'm voting you up, since it was a little bit of fun reminding me of my math self-learning times in college.